# How to assert video present on website?

Tags: testing, selenium, automation

I want to verify video presence on a website(For example, YouTube). Now the problem is that  I am not able locate an element that is video. I have used HTML as well as x-path. So how do I locate the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine the video should be contained in a Div, which should have an ID or Name? Have you tried just searching for the Div and asserting whether it has any elements or not? I think more information is required for a helpful answer.